# React-router-dom v4 not rendering component on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So basically I have a navbar that switches between routes. When the page loads, it goes to /home by default but doesn't actually render the App component it's being given. I have to click on the button that brings you to /home in order to render this.

I'm using react-router-dom with Redux.

Here's my BrowserRouter:

```
<Provider store = {store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Route exact path = "/home" component={App}> </Route>
        <Switch>
          <Route  path = "/about" render = {() => <AboutUs />}></Route>
          <Route  path = "/contact" render = {() => <Contact />}></Route>
          <Route  path = "/services" render = {() => <Services />}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Post the full component code. How is App imported? What does `App.js` look like?

Answer (score 0):

The default route is `/` not `/home`.
You need to setup a redirect.

`<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
    <Route exact path="/home" component={App} />
)} />`

Comment: OP says `When the page loads, it goes to /home by default `

Answer (score 0):

Put your `/home` route in the `Switch` with all the other routes:

```
<Provider store = {store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = "/home" component={App}> </Route>
          <Route  path = "/about" render = {() => <AboutUs />}></Route>
          <Route  path = "/contact" render = {() => <Contact />}></Route>
          <Route  path = "/services" render = {() => <Services />}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but App still doesn't render on load

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `/home` inside `<Switch>`

```
<Route exact path = "/home" component={App}> </Route>
```

Means put above line of code inside `<Switch>` 
ex:-

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path = "/home" component={App}> </Route>
      <Route  path = "/about" render = {() => <AboutUs />}></Route>
      <Route  path = "/contact" render = {() => <Contact />}></Route>
      <Route  path = "/services" render = {() => <Services />}></Route>
</Switch>
```